# process url with filename extension with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-4, url-routing

I currently using laravel 4.2 and nginx, now when i what to process the get request like '/img/300/200/dummy.png' with laravel controller, but it seems go to the files under the public folder , and not trig a laravel Route. how can i write controllers to process such url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have in nginx config something like:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
  add_header   Pragma public;
  add_header   Cache-Control "public";
  expires      max;
}
```

So nginx serves images directly without requesting php-fpm and Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your nginx config like that. Had a same problem as you

> ```
> location ~*/img/300/200/\.(png) {
>  try_files $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;    
> }
> ```